# GestureRecognizers from IB crashes app when simulating memory warning

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks, uigesturerecognizer, exc-bad-access

I have a gesture recognizer pulled from storyboard and it is working fine and dandy...

EXCEPT when I simulate a low memory warning. At that point, it crashes with the error:

```
[UISwipeGestureRecognizer retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x8627330
```

To get it to not crash, what I have to do is set the gesture recognizer as a strong property and comment out the autogenerated set to nil in viewdidload:

```
//[self setSwipeGestureRecognizer:nil];
```

I got to this solution randomly, and Im hoping someone can explain what is going on here?

Comment: That's very strange, because it generally removes views other than the current, active view. This is going to sound like a strange question, but how are you creating your view? `pushViewController` or `presentViewController`? Sometimes people try slight of hand when transitioning to new views (e.g. grabbing a view controller's view, but then disregarding the view controller itself), and I could easily imagine that might cause problems. You might want to insert NSLog statements (or debugger breakpoints) at all of your viewDidUnload statements, and make sure you know what's happening.

Comment: We might be able to help more with some more code. I assume your swipe gestures were created in `viewDidLoad`? And I assume you get this error when you initiate a swipe? Perhaps you can share your swipe handler, too.

Comment: View controllers were dragged out of storyboard, then gesture recognizers were dragged from storyboard onto the view controllers. I initially did not set them as Outlet propertys, but did set them as IBAction didSwipe. It was working fine except for this crash on low memory warning. What I had to do was set them as Outlet propertys and then comment out the [self setSwipeGestureRecognizer:nil] for it to not crash. Strange indeed.

Comment: When you say "set the gesture recognizer as a strong property", do I gather that you created an `IBOutlet` for it? I get this crash even if I have no outlet for the gesture, but rather just the `IBAction`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fascinating. When you first posted this I was assuming that there was some problem with your code, but given your clarifying comments, I decided to try it out myself. I experience the same behavior you do.

Specifically, I create a gesture recognizer in Interface Builder and linked it to an appropriate `IBAction` and confirmed it worked fine, even if I push to and pop from another view controller. But if I simulate a memory warning when at that secondary view controller, immediately upon return to the original view controller, I receive the same crash you do.

It's easily remedied. Looks like you have an approach, or you can simply bypass Interface Builder entirely, and create your own gesture recognizer in code, and you won't have this problem, e.g.,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    // [recognizer release]; // uncomment in non-ARC project
}
```

If you create it manually like this, you don't get the crash upon returning back to the view after simulating a memory warning. So that's your solve.

Fortunately, it looks like this has been remedied in the beta of the next version of Xcode and iOS.